# Why the output values are repeating? what should be the right query?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query i wrote, but when i execute the query the values are repeating. so help me to write the right query

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.NAME, 
       p.year, 
       p.address, 
       p.caste, 
       p.landextent, 
       p.adharno, 
       p.drillingdate, 
       p.pumpseterectiondate, 
       p.pumpsethp, 
       p.surveyno, 
       p.registrationdateinescom, 
       p.ymdmsdpaid, 
       p.ymdpaiddate, 
       p.energisationno, 
       p.energisationdate, 
       p.mobile, 
       p.remarks, 
       c.constituency_name   constituency, 
       t.NAME                taluka, 
       e.NAME                escom, 
       d.district_name       district, 
       division.divison_name division, 
       p.crsubmitted, 
       p.uniqueid, 
       p.yearofdrilling, 
       p.yearofpumpset, 
       p.yearofregistration, 
       p.yearofenergisation, 
       p.escomdivuseractive 
FROM   progress p 
       INNER JOIN constituency c 
               ON p.constituency_id = c.id 
       INNER JOIN taluka t 
               ON c.taluka_id = t.id 
       INNER JOIN district d 
               ON t.district_id = d.id 
       INNER JOIN divison di 
               ON d.divison_id = di.id 
       INNER JOIN divisons division 
               ON d.divisons_id = division.id 
       INNER JOIN escomdivison e 
               ON e.district_id = d.id 
WHERE  di.id = 3;
```

Comment: why are using table alias name is another table name `INNER JOIN divisons division` ?? use a different alias name

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the line

`INNER JOIN divisons division on d.divisons_id=division.id`

since you already have `division` table written on the one line above for the `INNER JOIN` conditions, and those(alias and table) are confused among them.

Comment: @SambitPanda from `divisons` or `divison` as table name..?

Comment: divison and divisions are two different tables .i want to show data based on divison